# How to set the work load model based on the actual request hits and TPM in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

For the given scenario in [sample scenarios image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzN9l.png) with duration 1hr , i tried to set the work load model as given below with the request hits 40000 and TPM 667:

Test Plan

```
thread group
      Loop controller
       Constant throughput timer
       JSR223sampler1 (sleep time 3000ms)
       JSR223sampler2 (sleep time 3000ms)
       JSR223sampler3 (sleep time 3000ms)
       JSR223sampler4 (sleep time 3000ms)
   summary report.
```

Since I am new to the Jmeter i am not able to set the values properly... Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) needs to be set up as:

   [image]
2. [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) should be allowed to iterate infinitely:

   [image]
3. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer/) should be applied to all active threads in the current Thread Group and the Target Throughput should be 667.0

   [image]

The above setup should fulfil the requirements for your scenario. Also be aware that sometimes the defined number of virtual users might be not enough to reach/maintain the desired throughput, in such cases it makes sense to consider using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) combination.